# Targeting a frame in frameset

Tags: frameset

I am working with framesets for an internet browser-based application that will be running on a local machine. I would like when an image is clicked to target another frame where details will appear. I tried to include "target=details" at the end of the image source as follows but that produced a sytax error:

**IMAGE code in gallery.php:**

```
<a href=details.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?> ><img src="./images/<?php echo $row['cfilename'] target=details;?>" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
```

**FRAMESET in index.php:**

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="17%,*">
   <FRAME SRC="titlebar.php" NAME=TITLE SCROLLING=NO>

   <FRAMESET COLS="26%,30%,*">
        <FRAME SRC="sidebar.php" NAME=sidebar TARGET=gallery>
        <FRAME SRC="gallery.php" NAME=gallery>
        <FRAME SRC="details.php" NAME=details>

   </FRAMESET>

   <NOFRAMES>
   <H1>Criminal Records Database</H1>
   No frames? No Problem! Take a look at our 
   <A HREF="index.php">no-frames</A> version.
   </NOFRAMES>

</FRAMESET>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add target="_nameofframe" to the href tag and tell it where to open the new link.
in your case, the href of the gallery images should have the following target="details"

i.e. 

`<a href=details.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?> ><img src="./images/<?php echo $row['cfilename'];?>" target="details" width="100" height="100" alt="" />`

Comment: You mean like in the first code above? It's what I have but am getting a sytax error.

Comment: Not like that... Do it the same way you write the alt, width and height... Target is an attribute hyperlinks.

Comment: do it like this : 
`<a href=details.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?> ><img src="./images/<?php echo $row['cfilename'];?>" target="details" width="100" height="100" alt="" />`